# Hyperledger Fabric - crash restore strategies

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, fault-tolerance

Yesterday faced with a nice problem: Nothing happens in case of chaincode container crash or someone manual stopping it.

Sample network (using v1.2.0 images):

- 2 **ORGs**
- 2 **CA's**
- 2 peers **ORG1** (using LevelDB as a storage)
- 2 peers **ORG2** (using LevelDB as a storage)
- 1 **solo orderer**
- 1 shared channel with consorcium of 2 **org's**
- this network is launched under the control of Docker Swarm on 4 VM's (2 manager's, 2 worker's nodes)

There are many elements that can break down:

- <strike>chaincode container crashes (!)</strike>
- one/two peer's of ORG1 crashes
- orderer crashes

So. The fabric's default behavior:

- <strike>chaincode container crashes (!)</strike>

*<strike>Stop processing sdk request's. no restart</strike>*
***UPD_1:*** With the next request (invoke/query) cc-container will be recreated

- one/two peer's of ORG1 crashes

*stop processing requests's due to lost connection to channel
after auto-restart/start on failure: lost connection to channel
if chaincode was instantiated on this peer: crash chaincode container*

So. What are the strategies/best practice to restore the Hyperledger Fabric network after crashes?